# Redirecting Input and Output of child process not working

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, process

I have coded two c++ app, one is console and the other is gui.
I want the gui app starts the console app and inserts input on it and redirect output and error and show them on the textbox.

my code does not work in gui app after pressing run button and does not show the output and it seems that the gui app freezes !

here is my code :

[console part]:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int pass;
//cout << "welcome message from cpp app ..." << endl;
cout << "please enter pass => ";
cin >> pass;
if (pass==12345)
    cout << "ok!" << endl;
else
    cout << "oops!" << endl;
//system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

[gui part]:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

#define TEXTBOX1 100
#define BUTTON1 101

HWND htbx = nullptr;
HANDLE hChildStd_IN_Rd = nullptr;
HANDLE hChildStd_IN_Wr = nullptr;
HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Rd = nullptr;
HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Wr = nullptr;

int MessageLoop();

void ShowError()
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    DWORD flags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS;
    FormatMessage(flags, nullptr, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), LPWSTR(&lpMsgBuf), 0, nullptr);
    MessageBox(nullptr, LPCWSTR(lpMsgBuf), L"error", MB_OK);
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}
void WriteToPipe(LPCWSTR Commands2Write) 
{
    DWORD dwWritten;
    bool bSuccess = false;
    bSuccess = WriteFile(hChildStd_IN_Wr, Commands2Write, sizeof(Commands2Write), &dwWritten, nullptr);
    if (!bSuccess)
        ShowError();
    if (!CloseHandle(hChildStd_IN_Wr))
        ShowError();
}
void ReadFromPipe()
{
    DWORD dwRead;
    LPVOID lpDataBuf[4096];

    if (hChildStd_OUT_Rd==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"INVALID HANDLE", L"error", MB_OK);
    }

    //bool bSuccess = false;
    /*bSuccess = ReadFile(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, lpDataBuf, 4096, &dwRead, nullptr);
    if (!bSuccess)
        ShowError();*/

    while (ReadFile(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, lpDataBuf, sizeof(lpDataBuf), &dwRead, nullptr))
    {
       SendMessage(htbx, WM_SETTEXT, 0, LPARAM(LPCWSTR(lpDataBuf)));
      // MessageBox(nullptr, LPCWSTR(lpDataBuf), L"Result", MB_OK);
    }
    LocalFree(lpDataBuf);

}
void Run()
{
    bool bSuccess = false;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    ZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI));
    STARTUPINFO SI;
    ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI));
    SI.cb = sizeof(SI);
    SI.dwFlags =  STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    //SI.hStdError = hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    //SI.hStdOutput = hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    //SI.hStdInput = hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    SI.hStdError = hChildStd_OUT_Rd;
    SI.hStdOutput = hChildStd_OUT_Rd;
    SI.hStdInput = hChildStd_IN_Wr;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SA;
    SA.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    SA.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    SA.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;

    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &SA, 0))
        ShowError();
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ShowError();
    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStd_IN_Rd, &hChildStd_IN_Wr, &SA, 0))
        ShowError();
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ShowError();
    bSuccess = CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
        L" /c C:\\testa.exe", nullptr, nullptr, TRUE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &SI, &PI);

    if (!bSuccess){ ShowError(); }
            else{CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);CloseHandle(PI.hThread);}

        WriteToPipe(L"12345");
        ReadFromPipe();
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CreateWindowEx(0, WC_BUTTON, L"Run", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 420, 100, 75, 35, hWnd, HMENU(BUTTON1), nullptr, nullptr);
        htbx=CreateWindowEx(0, WC_EDIT, L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER| ES_MULTILINE, 10, 10, 400, 300, hWnd, HMENU(TEXTBOX1), nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            case BUTTON1:
                Run();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPreviewInstance, LPSTR lpcmdline, int ncmdshow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wndexcls;
    wndexcls.lpszClassName = L"win";
    wndexcls.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndexcls.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndexcls.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndexcls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DSHADOW + 1);
    wndexcls.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndexcls.style = NULL;
    wndexcls.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndexcls.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndexcls.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndexcls.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndexcls.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    RegisterClassEx(&wndexcls);
    HWND Win_Handle = CreateWindowEx(0, L"win", L"TestApp", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 640, 380, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    ShowWindow(Win_Handle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(Win_Handle);

    int exitcode;
    exitcode = MessageLoop();
    return exitcode;
}

int MessageLoop()
{
    MSG wnd_msg;
    while (GetMessage(&wnd_msg, NULL, 0, 0)>0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&wnd_msg);
        DispatchMessage(&wnd_msg);
    }
    return (int)wnd_msg.wParam;
}
```

**Update:**

I have updated the code based on Barmak Shemirani`s answer and used ANSI character set. but the writetopipe part does not work and in the readfrompipe part, if you use "/c dir" as second parameter in CreateProcessA instead of "/c C:\consoleapp.exe" for example, it shows only the first line of output not the total output. why this happen ?

**[updated code]:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

#define TEXTBOX1 100
#define BUTTON1 101

HWND htbx = nullptr;
HANDLE out_read = NULL;
HANDLE out_write = NULL;
HANDLE in_read = NULL;
HANDLE in_write = NULL;

int MessageLoop();

void ShowError()
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    DWORD flags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS;
    FormatMessageA(flags, nullptr, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), LPSTR(&lpMsgBuf), 0, nullptr);
    MessageBoxA(nullptr, LPCSTR(lpMsgBuf), "error", MB_OK);
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}

void WriteToPipe() 
{
    DWORD writecount;
    char bufw[1024]; 
    //memset(bufw, 12345, 5);
    strncpy_s(bufw, "12345", sizeof(bufw));

    if (WriteFile(in_write, bufw, sizeof(bufw), &writecount, NULL))
    {
        if (!writecount)
        {
            ShowError();
        }

    }
    if (!CloseHandle(in_write))
        ShowError();

    LocalFree(bufw);
}
void ReadFromPipe()
{
    DWORD readCount;
    char bufr[1024];
    memset(bufr, 0, sizeof(bufr));
    if (ReadFile(out_read, bufr, sizeof(bufr), &readCount, NULL))
    {
        if (readCount)
        {
            SendMessageA(htbx, EM_SETSEL, WPARAM(-1), LPARAM(-1));
            SendMessageA(htbx, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, LPARAM(bufr));
        }
    }
    if (!CloseHandle(out_read))
        ShowError();

    LocalFree(bufr);
}
DWORD WINAPI run(LPVOID)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi{};
    STARTUPINFOA si{ sizeof STARTUPINFO };
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    { //set handles

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr;
        secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
        secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;

        if (!CreatePipe(&out_read, &out_write, &secAttr, 0)) ShowError();
        if (!SetHandleInformation(out_read, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) ShowError();
        if (!CreatePipe(&in_read, &in_write, &secAttr, 0)) ShowError();
        if (!SetHandleInformation(in_write, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) ShowError();

        si.hStdOutput = out_write;
        si.hStdError = out_write;
        si.hStdInput = in_read;
        si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    }

    if (!CreateProcessA("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
        "/c C:\\consoleapp.exe", 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
        ShowError();

    while (pi.hProcess && WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 25) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
        if (out_read == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ShowError();
        if (in_write == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ShowError();

        WriteToPipe();
        ReadFromPipe();
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CreateWindowExA(0, WC_BUTTONA, "Run", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 420, 100, 75, 35, hWnd, HMENU(BUTTON1), nullptr, nullptr);
        htbx=CreateWindowExA(0, WC_EDITA, "", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER| ES_MULTILINE, 10, 10, 400, 300, hWnd, HMENU(TEXTBOX1), nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            case BUTTON1:
                //Run();
                CreateThread(NULL, 0, run, 0, 0, NULL);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPreviewInstance, LPSTR lpcmdline, int ncmdshow)
{
    WNDCLASSEXA wndexcls;
    wndexcls.lpszClassName = "win";
    wndexcls.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndexcls.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndexcls.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndexcls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DSHADOW + 1);
    wndexcls.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndexcls.style = NULL;
    wndexcls.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndexcls.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndexcls.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndexcls.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndexcls.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    RegisterClassExA(&wndexcls);
    HWND Win_Handle = CreateWindowExA(0, "win", "TestApp", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 640, 380, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    ShowWindow(Win_Handle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(Win_Handle);
    int exitcode;
    exitcode = MessageLoop();
    return exitcode;
}

int MessageLoop()
{
    MSG wnd_msg;
    while (GetMessage(&wnd_msg, NULL, 0, 0)>0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&wnd_msg);
        DispatchMessage(&wnd_msg);
    }
    return (int)wnd_msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: `Run()` is called synchronously from your control handler. No other messages are dispatched, until `Run()` returns. This includes messages sent to the Edit control, so it will not update. You need to get a book to understand the event-based structure of a GUI application. [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) by Charles Petzold is the Gold Standard for Windows API programming.

Comment: Move `Run()` to a worker thread. You can still use `SendMessage()` in it, and the main thread will now be free to process those messages, as well as system messages, such as for UI painting and such.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : thanks for your help.

Comment: remove `WriteToPipe` out of the loop, put it immediately after `CreateProcess`, it might work once. When you `CloseHandle` then also set handle to invalid-value so you don't try to open it again. For example, `CloseHandle(out_read); out_read = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; ...` Your usage of `LocalFree` is correct in `ShowError`, because `FormatMessage` allocates memory, but in other areas there is no reason to put `LocalFree` unless you have called `LocalAlloc`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : Thanks for your tips. I have tested what you said and it did not work even once.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it makes sense to redirect both input and output for console window. If this is for exercise purposes then I have shown a simpler example to redirect console's output.

The console program seems to be ANSI, while the Windows program is UNICODE. This part gets confusing, you have to use ANSI API in some places.

```
DWORD WINAPI run(LPVOID)
{
    HANDLE out_read = NULL;
    HANDLE out_write = NULL;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi{};
    STARTUPINFO si{ sizeof STARTUPINFO };
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    { //set handles

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr;
        secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
        secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;

        if (!CreatePipe(&out_read, &out_write, &secAttr, 0)) error();
        if (!SetHandleInformation(out_read, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) error();

        si.hStdOutput = out_write;
        si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    }

    if (!CreateProcess(L"consoleProgram.exe", 0, 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
        error();

    while (pi.hProcess && WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 25) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
        if (out_read == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            break;

        DWORD readCount;
        char buf[1024];
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf);
        if (ReadFile(out_read, buf, sizeof(buf), &readCount, NULL))
        {
            if (readCount)
            {
                SendMessageA(hedit, EM_SETSEL, WPARAM(-1), LPARAM(-1));
                SendMessageA(hedit, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)buf);
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(...)
{
    ...
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            case BUTTON1:
                CreateThread(NULL, 0, run, 0, 0, NULL);
            ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, +1 UpVote for you. i have updated the code based on your answer but the read and write part needs to be fixed.

Comment: This code was working, it redirected console input to Windows. I tested it. But you have broken it, it's probably worse than it was before. You can't just randomly insert code without understanding what it does. It doesn't make sense to redirect both input and output. At best the console window sits there as black screen, but more likely the program crashes. Also there is no reason to use `"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"`. Windows could be installed to a different directory...

Comment: I know that Windows could be installed to a different directory. the  "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" is for eaxmple. you said "This code was working" but as i said in prev. comment, read and write part needs to be fixed. for this reason , i showed an eaxmple like this "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" and "/c dir " as argument and want to show that it does not redirect output properly. ofcourse it redirects output for consoleapp.exe properly !(Thanks for your help, +1 UpVote for you) but not for any console app like windows command prompt.

Comment: and why It doesn't make sense to redirect both input and output !? many console apps needs to enter input to show the desire output especially the console apps that you did not code yourself so you have to redirect  both input and output. and i did not randomly insert code without understanding what it does. i insert  the code based on my recognization of you answer and if it's probably worse than it was before, please correct me to the right way to solve this problem correctly and making your post as a accepted answer :)